# how does vbscript evaluate string greater than string?

Tags: c#, vbscript, code-conversion

i'm converting some vbscript from an asp app and ran across a line in the form of

```
If sCode > "" Then
```

where I expect `sCode` to contain a string. i know enough vbscript to plod through it but i'm not sure of the behavior of some quirkier statements. c# will not accept that as a valid condition check. what is an equivalent c# statement?

edit: extra thanks if someone can provide some documentation/reference for the vbscript behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in C# a string can also be `NULL`, I would use the following:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sCode))
    //do something
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a vbscript expert, but my hunch is vbscript overloaded `>` with strings to compare them ordinally. So if that is the case, then in C# `sCode.CompareTo(string.Empty)` will give you what you need, -1 if sCode less than the empty string (which is not possible in this case), 0 if they are equal, and 1 if sCode comes after.

In this particular case you can just check if sCode is the empty string though.

Comment: since the original code was checking against an empty string, the c# check can be reduced to RedFilter's example. if it were non-empty then i think `CompareTo` would be appropriate, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

I would just simply do !=, which appears to be the intent of the code:

```
if(sCode != String.Empty)
  Do();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case you simply compare to 'string.Empty' but the more generic answer is that it's (usually) a case insensitive alphanumeric comparison. E.g "ababa" < "z1asdf" is true. 
To represent that in C# you could do:

'string.Compare(A,B) < 0' which is equivallent of 'A

(usually) because it can be specified

Answer (score 0):

Use the "<>" (not equal to) operator, like so:

```
dim string
string = "hello"
if (string <> "") then
    WScript.Echo "We're Ok" & VbCrLf
else
    WScript.Echo "Empty String" & VbCrLf
End if
```